# JavaScript call() and Prototype - Slice Function

Tags: javascript, call, slice, apply

I'm reading the [MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) on `slice` in JavaScript. I understand everything except the 2nd example in the section titled *Array-Like Objects*.

It says we can simplify the first example by making `slice` our own function as so:

```
var unboundSlice = Array.prototype.slice;
var slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(unboundSlice);

function list() {
  return slice(arguments);
}

var list1 = list(1, 2, 3); // [1, 2, 3]
```

What I don't understand is how `call` can come right after `prototype` on the second line.

I usually see it in the form of `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` or something of that sort.

I don't understand the flow of the first two lines and how they generate this working `slice` function.

Comment: for what it's worth, you could also do `var slice = Array.prototype.slice.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);` though the point of your example is that `call` doesn't necessarily have to belong to the `slice` function initially, and it isn't bound to *any* function until you `bind` it.

Comment: Just as an object's `toString` method comes from `Object.prototype.toString`, a functions `call` method comes from `Function.prototype.call`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr:

```
var slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(unboundSlice);
```

is a short way of writing:

```
var slice = function(value, start, end) {
  return unboundSlice.call(value, start, end);
};
```

---

Let's think about this line for second:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
```

`.slice` is an array method to extract a subset of the array. It operates on the value of `this`. `.call` is a method every function has, it lets you set the `this` value for a function execution. So, the above line lets us execute `slice` as a method of `arguments`, without having to mutate `arguments` itself. We *could* have done

```
arguments.slice = Array.prototype.slice;
arguments.slice();
```

but that is not as clean.

Now looking at

```
Function.prototype.call.bind(unboundSlice);
```

As said, `.call` is a method that *every* function has. It also operates on `this`, which is expected to be a function. It calls `this` and sets the `this` value of that function to the first argument. You could think of `call` as being similar to

```
function call(thisValue, arg1, arg2, ...) {
   return this.apply(thisValue, [arg1, arg2, ...]);
}
```

Note how it calls `this` as a function.

`.bind` is also a method every function has. It returns a new function which has its `this` value fixed to the first argument you pass in.

Let's consider what the resulting function of `call.bind(unboundSlice)` would look like:

```
function boundCall(thisValue, arg1, arg2, ...) {
   return unboundSlice.apply(thisValue, [arg1, arg2, ...]);
}
```

We simply replaced `this` with `unboundSlice`. `boundCall` will now always call `unboundSlice`.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. I'll be reading through this many times. I feel like it's starting to click, it's only a matter of time.

Answer (score 4):

The [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for `Function.prototype.call()` helped me wrap my head around this.

The most simplistic way I can answer:

> In javascript, a Function has a method called `call`. A function is an
>   object, and all objects inherit methods and properties from their
>   prototype.

So your example of `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` shows you calling the call method on the slice function.

The second line in the code that you are confused about: `var slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(unboundSlice);` shows the call method belonging to the Function prototype.

Checkout [JavaScript Prototypes](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp) if you are still confused.

1 Functions are objects.

2 "Every JavaScript object has a prototype."

3 "The prototype is also an object."

4 "All JavaScript objects inherit their properties and methods from their prototype."

In other words, back to the most simplistic way to answer this: In javascript, a Function has a method called `call`.

As for understanding what `bind` does, the `that = this` vs `.bind` example in [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/) article helps make sense of what is going on.

If that was confusing, then make sure you understand [context and scope](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 2):

`slice` is a property of `Array.prototype`, and it expects its `this` object to be Array-like. You can use it on Array-like objects (that have a length property and have properties that you can index) that don't have their own slice function like so:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arraylikething);
```

That's a lot of typing, so we can make a function to do the same thing:

```
var slice = function(arraylikething){
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arraylikething);
};
```

JavaScript provides `Function.prototype.bind` to bind functions to a specified `this` object. So we can accomplish the same thing a bit more easily:

```
var slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);
```

`bind` creates a new function that returns the result of `call` with its `this` object set to `Array.prototype.slice`, the same as what we did manually above, and equivalent to your code.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Chris Dillinger is correct and informative.  But here's another way to think about it.  You're being asked, in essence, to define

```
Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice)
```

Which you can look at this way:

```
fn.bind(context) 
    ==>  function(...args) {return context.fn(...args);} 
            // 1. definition of `bind` (oversimplified, but enough for this case)

fn.bind(unboundSlice) 
    ==>  function(...args) {return unboundSlice.fn(...args);}  
            // 2. substitute `unboundSlice` for `context`

Function.prototype.call.bind(unboundSlice)
    ==>  function(...args) {return unboundSlice[Function.prototype.call](...args);} 
            // 3. substitute `Function.prototype.call` for `fn`.

Function.prototype.call.bind(unboundSlice)
    ==>  function(...args) {return unboundSlice[.call(...args);} 
            // 4. walk the prototype chain

Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice)
    ==>  function(...args) {return Array.prototype.slice.call(...args);}
            // 5. substitue `Array.prototype.slice` for `unboundSlice`
```

The only step that's even slightly tricky is step 4, where you have to realize that all functions inherit the `call` method from their prototype chain, so invoking `call` on them is merely an alternative means of invoking the functions themselves.

Comment: Laying this out step by step really helped me grasp this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line, `Array.prototype.slice` (which is a method) is simply referenced via `unboundSlice`. You're essentially 'extracting' the slice method from `Array.prototype`.

In the second line, the same thing happens for `Function.prototype.call`, which is also a method of ALL functions. (it's defined in `Function.prototype`, and inherited by all functions).

Next, by using `.bind(unboundSlice)` the Call function's `this` value is bound to the reference to `Array.prototype.slice`, which essentially results in the same thing as `Array.prototype.slice.call()`, where call also has its `this` bound to `slice`, because of it being a method of it, AND because it's being called like that.

Lastly, the bound call method is referenced via `var slice`;

The general idea here is that you're able to use the functionality of an array method (slice) in another context (the global scope).

So now, instead of calling `call` when it was already a method of `slice`, you're binding `slice` to be the `this` value of `call` in order to achieve the same behaviour.